# How to root a Xperia SP (C530x)?

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-sp

Simply, how to root a Sony Xperia SP device?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you looked at/seen? EDIT: This came up in the "low quality" list. I see what you've done with the question and answer provided (nice answer btw, +1).

Comment: @Peanut: didn't know how to write a better question... :)

Comment: Well the fact you provided the answer makes your question fine :) But in the queue you dont see any answers hence my original comment. If it had been a real question we'd expect more details of what people had tried but obviously that doesn't apply in this case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways, depending on your firmware version. They work on both locked & unlocked bootloader.

### Requirements

- Having adb drivers installed (usually installed with Sony PC Companion)
- Having enabled `Unknown Sources`
- Having enabled `USB Debugging`
- PC Companion must **not** be running

## 12.0.A.1.211/257 (C5302,C5303,C5306) ; 12.0.A.1.284 (C5302 only)

(credits for [DooMLoRD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=2784807), guide from [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2329208))

1. Download this [archive](http://d-h.st/Kmm) and extract it.
2. Connect your phone to your computer.
3. In the extracted folder, double click on the RUNME.bat file.
4. Follow the instructions (usually one key to tap).
5. Reboot your device if it doesn't do it itself.

## 12.0.A.2.245/254 (any device)

(credits for [DooMLoRD](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=2784807), guide from [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2405933))

In these versions, Sony has patched the exploit, so we need to flash an older kernel that has the exploit and then reflash the kernel of our actual firmware version. This requires [flashtool](http://www.flashtool.net/index.php).

1. Download this [archive](http://d-h.st/1Gp) and extract it.
2. Download the [kernel file](http://d-h.st/Kh7) from 1.257 firmware.
3. If your actual firmware version is 2.245, download this [kernel file](http://d-h.st/niC). If it is 2.254, download [this one](http://d-h.st/fv8).
4. Open flashtool, click on flash icon (see image), select flashmode, browse to 1.257 kernel ftf, validate. [image: Flashtool window.]
5. Disconnect your device, shut it down, then while *pushing on the volume down button* plug your device to your computer. The illumination bar should go green.
6. Wait for flashtool to finish, then reboot.
7. **CLOSE FLASHTOOL**
8. In the extracted folder, run the runme_ file (exact name depends on your OS).
9. Once it is finished, shutdown your device.
10. Open Flashtool again, repeat the same steps as before, but select the kernel FTF for your actual version (2.245 or 2.254).
11. Plug your device in Flashmode.
12. When flashtool has finished, you can reboot and finally enjoy your root!

## Jelly Bean 4.3 (12.1.A.0.266) (any device)

*As for 12.0.A.2.245 and 12.0.A.2.254, the exploit is fixed, so we need to root while being on an older firmware (2.254 preferably), flash the new stock rom zip via recovery and flash the new kernel via Flashtool.*
(thanks to [niaboc79](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=599722) for this method).

1. Downloads:

   - 12.1.A.0.266 FTF (Full or Kernel Only)
   - [Recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2514471&d=1389669698)
   - [Stock ROM deodexed](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2628969) or any stock based ROM of your choice
   - [SuperUser Fix](https://mega.co.nz/#!lY1hHYqC!J9ireBCZBitNVlWIPDerFVst_7JIJd8QK8XnkgdX_FE)
2. Update to 12.0.A.2.254.
3. Root using the 2nd method.
4. **CLOSE FLASHTOOL**
5. Unzip the recovery archive and run the .bat file.
6. Put the ROM and fix zip on your phone.
7. Reboot in recovery (Power Off your phone, then power on and press (not maintain) volume up on multiple times until it vibrates).
8. Flash the ROM.
9. Flash the fix.
10. *Advanced -> Power Off*
11. **IF IT ASK YOU ABOUT A SU OVERWRITE, SELECT NO**
12. Open flashtool and flash **only the kernel** from the .266 ftf. (see screenshot from [niaboc79](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=599722)) [image]
13. Unplug, power on and enjoy Android 4.3 with root!

Comment: I used towelroot to root my xperia sp. Just installed towel root and ran the app. It worked. https://towelroot.com/