# Xperia sp c502 rooting

Tags: rooting, custom-roms

I want to root my *Xperia SP C502*. Can anyone tell me how I can root it?

I know there is chance that rooting can completely destroy my mobile. In that case: is their any solution to repair, and is rooting and downloading custom ROM for free?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575). It links e.g. to a solution for the [Xperia SP (C530x)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63123/16437), which seems to be quite close to yours.

Comment: I didn't even understand a thing what u have wrote

Comment: Then it's hard to help you. Did you follow the links?

Comment: Yeah I followed links I understood sry about previos comment can u tell me is there any solution if I have totally bricked my device

Comment: That's another question altogether. I recommend asking that separately. This question is about "how to root the Xperia SP C502", right? "Can I unbrick a wracked device" is a different topic (this site works best with exactly one question/topic per post). Before posting that separate question, please check our [unbrick tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/unbricking/info) and its questions, especially [What's my solutions if i brick my android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10521/16575)

Comment: Last question is rooting worth the risk?

Comment: See our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info). The [root tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/root/info) might also cover some of that. I remember we already have a question for this: [I've rooted my phone. Now what? What do I gain from rooting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1/16575)